# How to bind TextBox to multiple datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to update the Person data in batch.

```
public class Person
{
    public long personID { get; set; }
    public long FirstName { get; set; }
    public long LastName { get; set; }
    public long Department { get; set; }
}
```

List m_list = new List();

I have a TextBox "TextBox1" control which I want to bind to "Department" attribute of every Person of m_list.

```
foreach(Person current in m_list)
{
    //string bindingPath = "Department";
    //Binding binding = new Binding(bindingPath);
    //binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    //binding.Source = current;
    //TextBox1.SetBinding(TextBox1.Text, binding);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to bind multiple Departments into the TextBox if it can display only one? I din't understand the intended usage, can you clarify your intention?

Comment: I don't think I understand this. It sounds like you want to bind the `Department` property from multiple `Person` objects to one textbox? How do you envision that working with two way binding?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to do in your view model with something like this:

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        private readonly Lazy<ObservableCollection<Person>> _people = new Lazy<ObservableCollection<Person>>(
            () =>
                {
                    return new ObservableCollection<Person>
                            {
                                new Person {Department = "Dept1", FirstName = "Person", LastName = "1"},
                                new Person {Department = "Dept2", FirstName = "Person", LastName = "2"},
                            };
                });
        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get { return _people.Value; } }

        public string Department
        {
            set
            {
                foreach (var p in People)
                    p.Department = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Department, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Grid.Column="1">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,15">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Department}"/>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                   <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
                                   <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                                 </MultiBinding> 
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding the `DataContext`

WPF applications contain two layers: the UI layer and the data layer. The `DataContext` is the data layer, while your controls (such as a `TextBox`) is the UI layer.

If you want to update your data in a batch, simply perform your update in the data layer. You do not need to get the UI layer involved at all (unless you're getting a value from it).

For example, if you have a single `TextBox` and you want to set the `Department` property of every `Person` in the `List<Person>` to `TextBox.Text`, then simply loop through your `Person` list, and set the `Department` property of each one to `TextBox1.Text`

```
foreach(Person current in m_list)
{
    current.Department = TextBox1.Text;
}
```